# Insert a <br /> tag programmatically (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, literals

I'm trying to dynamically add results to this display and I simply want to put a break tag after a label to start putting information on the next line.  For some reason, Using a literal isn't working for me.  Is there a better way to do this or should I just use tables?

```
Dim break As LiteralControl
break = New LiteralControl("<br />")
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(break)
```

That's part of the code that I'm attempting to use.

---

Let me clarify what I said:

It's not working as in the line break isn't showing up on the webpage.  It's compiling fine and there is nothing wrong with the code.  It just doesn't show up in the html for some odd reason.

Comment: Why not add another label, or append the previous label.txt with a break?

Comment: I don't know VB.NET, but break is a reserved word in C#. Are you getting a compiler warning for using it?

Comment: madcolor: Not a bad idea.

Out Into Space: Nope.

Comment: I would take a look at my answer, while a label will work it is a bit of a hack.  The proper control to use is the HtmlGenericControl as it was built for situations just like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper control to use is the [`HtmlGenericControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(VS.71).aspx).

```
Dim br As New HtmlGenericControl("br")
```

You can use the `HtmlGenericControl` to render any HTML element you wish, simply pass the element's tag name as a single argument to the constructor.

Comment: Cool!  Was not aware of the HtmlGenericControl previously.  Thx.

Comment: This isn't working either.  The break tag appear nowhere in the html.

Comment: It sounds like any new controls you create are not being added to the ControlCollection of the Page itself.  You ought to verify that the control itself is actually being added.

Comment: Only 2 of the 10 "br" controls are being added.  I step through and it hits all 10 of them.  Any ideas as to why they aren't being shown in the actual html?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing more code - that does sounds really strange though.

Comment: HtmlGenericControl("br") will render as <br></br>
LiteralControl("<br />") is what you want to use.  If it's not rendering, there is an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: how exactly can I use put this in a line in my html file? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use another label, or append the `<br>` to the previous label.txt?

Comment: Voted Andrew +1, as I believe he has a cleaner more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the added 
 is the last element in the container div, you can not see any difference.

you can try :

```
Dim breakTag As LiteralControl
breakTag= New LiteralControl("<br />&nbsp;")
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(breakTag)
```

to see the break.

But I think you should first add a dummy text into this Literal and search for it in your page if it's added. because your code looks fine.

Comment: I put some generic text in the LiteralControl and it only shows up 2 of 10 times in the html. Any clue as to why that is?  I stepped through it and the line of code is getting hit, but nothing results of it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is reviving an old post but I didn't see any clear answer and I finally figured it out for my own application. Hope it helps someone else! 
In my application  I tried to create the control once and add it again wherever I needed it. The control would only be created once per parent.
**You need to create a new control every time you need it!** 
So this:

```
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("&lt;br />"))
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("&lt;br />"))
```

Instead of this

```
Dim breakTag As LiteralControl
breakTag= New LiteralControl("&lt;br />")
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(breakTag)
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(breakTag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if break is a reserve word also in vb.net so try

```
Dim newline = New LiteralControl("<br>")
```

or

```
newline.Text="<br>";
```

Comment: I changed the variable name to make sure, and it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would try stepping through the code with a debugger to make sure the line gets hit, also  triple-check that `divListenerInfo` is the right control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a panel or placeholder.

vb.net or C# .net syntax:

```
divListenerInfo.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("< br >"))
```

Comment: I doubt leaving the "/" out is going to change much, and may break his page... or did you maybe answer before reading the whole page?