# put a block of code to an html file from vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, google-maps

```
Dim br As New HtmlGenericControl("br")
```

saw that here. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799226/insert-a-br-tag-programmatically-vb-net)

I think that's the idea, but correct me if I am wrong..
I am working on a project that needs googlemaps, so I put a webBrowser, and summon the page. now, I need to add another marker dynamically through VB.
this is what I wanted to put to an html page after clicking a button.
(codefor adding a marker + some function)

```
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.580235, 121.058858);    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myLatlng, map:map, icon:camera ,draggable:true});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function()
        {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

          setTimeout(function()
              {
            mCamView1.Camera = 1; 
            mCamView1.Host = "192.168.1.1:12345" 
            mCamView1.play = 1; 
            mCamView1.Command = "SetPass -4 guest guest"; 
            mCamView1.ShowText = 7; 
            mCamView1.ShowInfo = 1;
              }, 2000);
        });
```

is this possible in VB? also, I am not only putting one. means, I need to add more, and more means change in variables and values TIA

EDIT: I am not using ASP.net